# How to export a Pydantic model instance as YAML with URL type as string

Tags: python, yaml, pydantic, pyyaml

I have a Pydantic model with a field of type `AnyUrl`.
When exporting the model to YAML, the `AnyUrl` is serialized as individual field slots, instead of a single string URL (perhaps due to how the `AnyUrl.__repr__` method is [implemented](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/cc54acb612cb5144a34caebb9ac143324a0cb4a1/pydantic/networks.py#L333-L335)).

For example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, AnyUrl
import yaml

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    url: AnyUrl


data = {'url': 'https://www.example.com'}
model = MyModel.parse_obj(data)

y = yaml.dump(model.dict(), indent=4)
print(y)
```

Produces:

```yaml
url: !!python/object/new:pydantic.networks.AnyUrl
    args:
    - https://www.example.com
    state: !!python/tuple
    - null
    -   fragment: null
        host: www.example.com
        host_type: domain
        password: null
        path: null
        port: null
        query: null
        scheme: https
        tld: com
        user: null
```

Ideally, I would like the serialized YAML to contain `https://www.example.com` instead of individual fields.

I have tried to override the `__repr__` method of `AnyUrl` to return the `AnyUrl` object itself, as it extends the `str` class, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [`pyyaml` documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) is just horrendous, so seemingly elemental things like customizing (de-)serialization are a pain to figure out properly. But there are essentially two ways you could solve this.

### Option A: Subclass [`YAMLObject`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#yamlobject)

You had the right right idea of subclassing `AnyUrl`, but the `__repr__` method is irrelevant for YAML serialization. For that you need to do three things:

1. Inherit from `YAMLObject`,
2. define a custom `yaml_tag`, and
3. override the `to_yaml` classmethod.

Then `pyyaml` will serialize this custom class (that inherits from both `AnyUrl` and `YAMLObject`) in accordance with what you define in `to_yaml`.

The `to_yaml` method always receives exactly two arguments:

1. A [`yaml.Dumper`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#dumper) instance with built-in capabilities to serialize standard types (via methods like `represent_str` for example) and
2. the actual data to be serialized.

To avoid adding/overriding additional methods, you can leverage the fact that `AnyUrl` inherits from string and the underlying [`str.__new__`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.8/pydantic/networks.py#L185) method actually receives the *full* URL during construction. Therefore the `str.__str__` method will return that "as is".

```py
from pydantic import AnyUrl, BaseModel
from yaml import Dumper, ScalarNode, YAMLObject, dump, safe_load


class Url(AnyUrl, YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = "!Url"

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, dumper: Dumper, data: str) -> ScalarNode:
        return dumper.represent_str(str.__str__(data))


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    foo: int = 0
    url: Url


obj = MyModel.parse_obj({"url": "https://www.example.com"})
print(obj)

serialized = dump(obj.dict()).strip()
print(serialized)

deserialized = MyModel.parse_obj(safe_load(serialized))
print(deserialized == obj and isinstance(deserialized.url, Url))
```

Output:

```
foo=0 url=Url('https://www.example.com', scheme='https', host='www.example.com', tld='com', host_type='domain')
```

```yaml
foo: 0
url: https://www.example.com
```

```
True
```

---

### Option B: Register a [*representer*](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#constructors-representers-resolvers) function for `AnyUrl`

You can avoid defining your own subclass and instead **globally** register a function that defines how instances of `AnyUrl` should be serialized, by using the `yaml.add_representer` function.

That function takes two mandatory arguments:

1. The class for which you want to define your custom serialization behavior and
2. the *representer* function that defines that serialization behavior.

The representer function essentially has to have the same signature as the `YAMLObject.to_yaml` classmethod presented in option A, i.e. it takes a `Dumper` instance and the data to be serialized as arguments.

```py
from pydantic import AnyUrl, BaseModel
from yaml import Dumper, ScalarNode, add_representer, dump, safe_load


def url_representer(dumper: Dumper, data: AnyUrl) -> ScalarNode:
    return dumper.represent_str(str.__str__(data))


add_representer(AnyUrl, url_representer)


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    foo: int = 0
    url: AnyUrl


obj = MyModel.parse_obj({"url": "https://www.example.com"})
print(obj)

serialized = dump(obj.dict()).strip()
print(serialized)

deserialized = MyModel.parse_obj(safe_load(serialized))
print(deserialized == obj and isinstance(deserialized.url, AnyUrl))
```

Output is the same as with the code from option A.

The benefit of this approach is that it involves less code and potential namespace collisions between the two parent classes in option A.

A potential drawback is that it modifies a **global** setting for the entire runtime of the program, which can become less transparent, if your application becomes large and is just something to be aware of, in case you decide you want to serialize `AnyUrl` objects differently at some point.