# YAML representation of a dictionary from multi-level Ctype Structure gets a strange object

Tags: python, ctypes, pyyaml

**TL;DR: I have a ctype Structure with another Structure inside, which I convert (seemingly correct) to a python dictionary, then I attempt to dump it into YAML. However the value of the internal Structure is shown wrong.**

Python version: 3.10
Pyyaml version: 6.0

Background: I am trying to make our internal configuration handling more user-friendly. Our configuration files are the serialized copy of data from a C structure, and until now it was changed manually via hexeditor. My plan is to make this process more human readable, in a short term reading and writing YAML files.

I am using Ctypes Structure to serialize and deserialize the data, mainly because I have to support bitfields. The Ctype Structure could be used as a template, without actual values in it.

I have simplified the code by removing irrelevant functions and shortening the structures.

```py
class substruct_t(My_Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("app", c_uint8, 4),
        ("showScale", c_uint8, 2),
        ("showIdleTemp", c_uint8, 2),
        ("type", c_uint8),
    ]

class ee_struct(My_Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("txStatusDelay", c_uint8, 5),
        ("overrideHours", c_uint8, 3),
        ("manualSet", c_int16),
        ("tempOffset", c_int8),

        ("substruct", substruct_t),

        ("LogArr", (c_uint8*6)*3),
        ("frostTemp", c_int8),
        ("fileVer", c_uint8*4),
    ]

class eeprom_t(Union):
    _fields_ = [("as_struct", ee_struct), ("as_bytes", c_uint8*29)]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.as_struct)
    
    def get_as_dict(self):
        return self.as_struct.as_dict()
    
    def get_as_bytes(self):
        return np.ndarray((29, ), 'b', self.as_bytes, order='C')
```

I have created a `My_Structure` class, which inherits from Ctypes `Structure`, and allows different representation of the data, including dict. This seems to work well.

```py
# Child class of Structure with string and dictionary representation functions, unwrapping arrays
class My_Structure(Structure):
    def __recursive_carray_get(self, value):
        # Necessary recursive function, if value is ctype array
        if hasattr(value, '__len__'):
            rtn = list()
            for i in range(value.__len__()):
                rtn.append(self.__recursive_carray_get(value.__getitem__(i)))
        else:
            rtn = value
        return rtn

    def __handle_array_type__(self, type):
        # example unformatted type: <class '__main__.c_ubyte_Array_6_Array_3'>
        return StringBetween("'", "'", str(type)).split(".")[1]
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.as_dict())

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        values = ",\n".join(f"{name}={value['value']}" for name, value in self.as_dict().items())
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__}: {values}>"
    
    def as_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {field[0]: {'value': self.__recursive_carray_get(getattr(self, field[0])), 'type': self.__handle_array_type__(field[1])}
                for field in self._fields_}
```

However when I want to dump this dict into a YAML file, the value of `substruct` within `ee_sruct` is dumped badly, like a python object. I do not understand why, as a typecheck shows it is still a dict.

```
 ### Dict representation of substructure:
{'value': {'app': {'value': 2, 'type': 'c_ubyte'}, 'showScale': {'value': 0, 'type': 'c_ubyte'}, 'showIdleTemp': {'value': 1, 'type': 'c_ubyte'}, 'type': {'value': 2, 'type': 'c_ubyte'}}, 'type': 'substruct_t'}

 ### pyyaml dump of entire structure:
txStatusDelay: {value: 8, type: c_ubyte}
overrideHours: {value: 1, type: c_ubyte}
manualSet: {value: 100, type: c_short}
tempOffset: {value: 0, type: c_byte}
substruct:
  value: !!python/object/apply:_ctypes._unpickle
  - !!python/name:__main__.substruct_t ''
  - !!python/tuple
    - {}
    - !!binary |
      QgI=
  type: substruct_t
LogArr:
  value:
  - [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  - [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  - [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  type: c_ubyte_Array_6_Array_3
frostTemp: {value: 16, type: c_byte}
fileVer:
  value: [65, 66, 104, 0]
  type: c_ubyte_Array_4
```

If I use a hardcoded dict with the exact same contents I get from `get_as_dict`, everything works.

Apparently, the dump functions don't get the same data as what gets printed from `get_as_dict`. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

**What I tried:**

My first idea was to implement a recursive function to return `dict` for internal structures (similarly what I did for arrays), but I was not sure where to start, as `substruct` is already reported as `dict`, and using the string (hardcoded) representation works.

[How to export a Pydantic model instance as YAML with URL type as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76385999/how-to-export-a-pydantic-model-instance-as-yaml-with-url-type-as-string) seemed like a good approach, but combining `Structure` and `YAMLObject` resulted in a metaclass conflict, which I was unable to resolve.

I tried to dump into Json or using ruamel.yml, both throw an exception, complaining about `substruct_t`.

[Combining Dumper class with string representer to get exact required YAML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793013/combining-dumper-class-with-string-representer-to-get-exact-required-yaml-output) could be the right approach, however it looks quite complicated, and I am hoping, there is a more simple solution that I just overlooked.

I just found a dirty fix, following the steps:

- convert the dict from `get_as_dict()` to a string
- replace all `'` characters to `"`
- use `json.loads()` on the string to create a new dict, and use that instead
  It works, but it just underlines my question, why are the two dicts different to the dumpers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

The problem is that *__recursive_carray_get*, does what it name suggests (handles arrays, which is consistent).

**But**, when it comes to (sub) structures, it doesn't handle them (or it handles them as any basic type):

1. So, when the *ee_struct* instance is serialized to a dictionary (by calling its *as_dict* method), **the value corresponding to the *substruct* key is actually a *substruct_t* instance**
2. Due to the fact that *__repr__* is overridden (to also use *as_dict*), when printing the dictionary, **the *substruct_t* instance is also displayed as a dictionary, masking the previous error**

I fixed the errors in your code, and added some other improvements (with minimum changes).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys
from pprint import pprint as pp

import yaml


class SerializableStructure(cts.Structure):
    @classmethod
    def _as_dict(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, cts.Array):
            ret = [cls._as_dict(e) for e in value]
        elif hasattr(value, "as_dict"):
            ret = value.as_dict()
        else:
            ret = value
        return ret

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.as_dict())

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        values = ",\n".join(f"{name}={value['value']}" for name, value in self.as_dict().items())
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__}: {values}>"

    def as_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {f[0]: {"value": self._as_dict(getattr(self, f[0])), "type": f[1].__name__}
                for f in self._fields_}


class Substruct_t(SerializableStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (
        ("app", cts.c_uint8, 4),
        ("showScale", cts.c_uint8, 2),
        ("showIdleTemp", cts.c_uint8, 2),
        ("type", cts.c_uint8),
    )


class EEStruct(SerializableStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (
        ("txStatusDelay", cts.c_uint8, 5),
        ("overrideHours", cts.c_uint8, 3),
        ("manualSet", cts.c_int16),
        ("tempOffset", cts.c_int8),
        ("substruct", Substruct_t),
        ("LogArr", (cts.c_uint8 * 6) * 3),
        ("frostTemp", cts.c_int8),
        ("fileVer", cts.c_uint8 * 4),
    )


def main(*argv):
    ees = EEStruct()
    marker = "----------"
    print("{:s} Original object {:s}".format(marker, marker))
    print(ees)
    d = ees.as_dict()
    print("\n{:s} Type: {:} {:s}".format(marker, type(d["substruct"]["value"]), marker))  # @TODO - cfati: Check for the old implementation
    print("\n{:s} Dictionary representation {:s}".format(marker, marker))
    pp(d)
    print("\n{:s} YAML representation {:s}".format(marker, marker))
    print(yaml.dump(d))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076458298]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> ---------- Original object ----------
> <EEStruct: txStatusDelay=0,
> overrideHours=0,
> manualSet=0,
> tempOffset=0,
> substruct={'app': {'value': 0, 'type': 'c_ubyte'}, 'showScale': {'value': 0, 'type': 'c_ubyte'}, 'showIdleTemp': {'value': 0, 'type': 'c_ubyte'}, 'type': {'value': 0, 'type': 'c_ubyte'}},
> LogArr=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
> frostTemp=0,
> fileVer=[0, 0, 0, 0]>
>
> ---------- Type: <class 'dict'> ----------
>
> ---------- Dictionary representation ----------
> {'LogArr': {'type': 'c_ubyte_Array_6_Array_3',
>             'value': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]},
>  'fileVer': {'type': 'c_ubyte_Array_4', 'value': [0, 0, 0, 0]},
>  'frostTemp': {'type': 'c_byte', 'value': 0},
>  'manualSet': {'type': 'c_short', 'value': 0},
>  'overrideHours': {'type': 'c_ubyte', 'value': 0},
>  'substruct': {'type': 'Substruct_t',
>                'value': {'app': {'type': 'c_ubyte', 'value': 0},
>                          'showIdleTemp': {'type': 'c_ubyte', 'value': 0},
>                          'showScale': {'type': 'c_ubyte', 'value': 0},
>                          'type': {'type': 'c_ubyte', 'value': 0}}},
>  'tempOffset': {'type': 'c_byte', 'value': 0},
>  'txStatusDelay': {'type': 'c_ubyte', 'value': 0}}
>
> ---------- YAML representation ----------
> LogArr:
>   type: c_ubyte_Array_6_Array_3
>   value:
>   - - 0
>     - 0
>     - 0
>     - 0
>     - 0
>     - 0
>   - - 0
>     - 0
>     - 0
>     - 0
>     - 0
>     - 0
>   - - 0
>     - 0
>     - 0
>     - 0
>     - 0
>     - 0
> fileVer:
>   type: c_ubyte_Array_4
>   value:
>   - 0
>   - 0
>   - 0
>   - 0
> frostTemp:
>   type: c_byte
>   value: 0
> manualSet:
>   type: c_short
>   value: 0
> overrideHours:
>   type: c_ubyte
>   value: 0
> substruct:
>   type: Substruct_t
>   value:
>     app:
>       type: c_ubyte
>       value: 0
>     showIdleTemp:
>       type: c_ubyte
>       value: 0
>     showScale:
>       type: c_ubyte
>       value: 0
>     type:
>       type: c_ubyte
>       value: 0
> tempOffset:
>   type: c_byte
>   value: 0
> txStatusDelay:
>   type: c_ubyte
>   value: 0
>
>
> Done.
> ```

For more details on the same (or similar) topic, check:

- [[SO]: Pickling a ctypes.Structure with ct.Pointer (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72525657/4788546)
- [[GitHub]: CristiFati/cfpyutils - cfpyutils/ctypes.py](https://github.com/CristiFati/cfpyutils/blob/master/ctypes.py)

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive answer, I made the changes and now it works as expected! I have also noted your other changes for the future.